# Split the ceiling fan and light to separate power. Need the power to be controlled by each switch

Tags: electrical

Have a ceiling fan with single wiring for both fan and light. I would like to split one switch into 2 so the fan and light can be controlled separately.

Comment: You *probably* will have to run a new cable from the switch to the ceiling fan/light depending on what you have right now. The fan/light have a common neutral so you need two hots and one neutral in the same cable. This means you need a 14-3 + ground (or 12-3 + gnd if this is a 20 A circuit. What is the cable now between the switch and the fan--black, white and ground? .

Comment: Shoot us a photo of what's going on inside the fan or switch box...

Comment: Yes, can you get us a photo of the inside of the box?

Comment: Jim is right. The easiest solution is installing a wireless remote switch with the receiver in the fan canopy. I've done this several times and most are very reliable with separate controls for light and fan speed. The toggle switch on the wall supplies power and the remote controls function.

Comment: Alternatively, if possible with the wiring at the fan and type of fan, consider having the fan always wired and switched by the pull chain, while the light is switched st the wall.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two independent wall switches, you would have to run a new cable from the switch to the ceiling fan/light depending on what you have right now.

(I am assuming that you have NM cable, not wires in conduit.)  What is the cable now between the switch and the fan--black, white and ground?

The fan/light have a common neutral so you need two hots and one neutral in one cable. This means you need a 14-3 + ground (or 12-3 + gnd if this is a 20 A circuit).

An alternative solution is to put in a wireless switch with the receiver placed in the shroud of the fan. If would do this, then you could keep the 14-2 cable.

The wireless switch would mount on the surface of the wall or could just be laid on a piece of furniture. The remote switch comes with a bracket allowing mounting over the existing switch so you would not have to make new holes in the wall. These wireless switches have separate buttons for fan and light, but they are a possible point of failure. I have two fans with these remotes: [Hunter universal remote](https://www.grainger.com/product/45PE01?gclid=CjwKCAiAwojkBRBbEiwAeRcJZI-qvQGve4lQKZgZPKNmnfdSIiXlAqsyAjqbuUOFyEXnHVJWYO-pCxoC0cUQAvD_BwE&cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20PLA&ef_id=CjwKCAiAwojkBRBbEiwAeRcJZI-qvQGve4lQKZgZPKNmnfdSIiXlAqsyAjqbuUOFyEXnHVJWYO-pCxoC0cUQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!264922886862!!!g!437522950559!)